# issues with progress bar files uploads via reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The code below uploads files to server but the file upload progress is not working.

**I have set the Progress state to 0**
Set  the following codes withing axios call but cannot get the progress bar counting to work

```
var config = {
      onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
              let progress = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
      }
 };
```

Below is the code

```
//import React from 'react';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios, { post } from 'axios';


class FilePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value:'', file: '', myfile:'', progress : 0};


    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }


_handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

 const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('myfile', this.state.file);

var config = {
      onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
              let progress = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
      }
 };

axios.post('http://localhost/server.php', formData, config).then((res) => {


}).catch((err) => {
console.log(err.message);
});




  }



// handle form submission
 handleChange(event) {

    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }


  render() {

    return (




      <div>


        <form onSubmit={(e)=>this._handleSubmit(e)}>
          <input className="fileInput"  type="file" value={this.state.myfile}  onChange={(e)=>this._handleImageChange(e)}  name="myfile"/>



          <progress   value = {this.state.progress} min = "0" max="100">0%</progress>
          <br/><br/>
          <span>Uploading: {this.state.progress}%</span>
          <h3> {this.state.progress} </h3>






          <button className="submitButton" 
            type="submit" 
            onClick={(e)=>this._handleSubmit(e)}>Upload Image</button>
        </form>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call setState inside your onUploadProgress

```
const config = {
  onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
    let progress = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
    this.setState({ progress });
  }
};
```

Also, show state.progress inside your render, instead of 0:

```
<progress value={this.state.progress} min="0" max="100">
  {this.state.progress}%
</progress>
```

Comment: it is the recommended approach to have a function inside setState so let's encourage it https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1

Comment: I think the purpose of the function is when relying on a previous React state, but here it's only relying on `progressEvent` which is independent of the state (it's from `axios`). The article mentions their use case: `I am relying on the value of this.state.showForm to modify the next state of my form...`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tudor.gergely but the code could not be compiled as it throws error unexpected token at `...s`

Comment: Try now, made an edit.  seems like you are using some older version of js. @stackoveflow-newbie made you change idea :)